# Why does heroku give me EACCES 34.200.126.31:443 error?

Tags: python, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

guys, I'm having this problem I can't seem to find a solution for it.
I downloaded the Heroku CLI for windows, the Heroku command seems to be working but whenever i type

```
$heroku login
```

It gives 
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:

Then this line comes:
Error: connect EACCES 34.200.126.31:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)

Comment: Windows (or any other) firewall?

Comment: K7, does it do anything, if yes then what should I block

Answer (score 0):

disable simplewall or similar software (*which blocks telemetry*) if you use it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).